# How to convert String to UnsafePointer<UInt8> and length

Tags: string, swift

When I using `NSOutputStream`'s `write` method

```
func write(_ buffer: UnsafePointer<UInt8>, maxLength length: Int) -> Int
```

I don't know how to convert `String`  to `UnsafePointer<UInt8>` and length

How can I do this in swift?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to convert the string to UTF-8 data first

```
let string = "foo bar"
let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!
```

and then write it to the output stream

```
let outputStream: NSOutputStream = ... // the stream that you want to write to
let bytesWritten = outputStream.write(UnsafePointer(data.bytes), maxLength: data.length)
```

The `UnsafePointer()` cast is necessary because `data.bytes` has the type `UnsafePointer<Void>`, and not `UnsafePointer<UInt8>` as expected by the `write()`
method.

---

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
let string = "foo bar"
// Conversion to UTF-8 data (cannot fail):
let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! 

// Write to output stream:
let outputStream: NSOutputStream = ... // the stream that you want to write to
let bytesWritten = data.withUnsafeBytes { outputStream.write($0, maxLength: data.count) }
```

Answer (score 17):

Here is how to do it in Swift 3. Run fine in Swift 4 too

```
extension String {

  func toPointer() -> UnsafePointer<UInt8>? {
    guard let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else { return nil }

    let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: data.count)
    let stream = OutputStream(toBuffer: buffer, capacity: data.count)

    stream.open()
    data.withUnsafeBytes({ (p: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> Void in
      stream.write(p, maxLength: data.count)
    })

    stream.close()

    return UnsafePointer<UInt8>(buffer)
  }
}
```

To convert from `String` to `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>`

```
let cString = strdup("Hello") // UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>
```

To convert from `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>` to `String`

```
let string = String(cString: cString!) // String
```

Comment: It's important to keep in mind that the `toPointer()` function returns a pointer to memory allocated on the heap and as such, you should `free()` it when you are finished with it to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4**,

Convert String to NSString, then use NSString's methods.

```
let text = "Hello"
let pointer: UnsafePointer<Int8>? = NSString(string: text).utf8String
let length = NSString(string: text).length
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also let Swift do it for you!

```
import Foundation

// Example function:
func printUTF8Vals(_ ptr: UnsafePointer<UInt8>, _ len: Int) { 
    for i in 0..<len { 
        print(ptr[i]) 
    } 
} 

// Call it:
let str = "Hello"
printUTF8Vals(str, str.lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8))

// Prints:
// 72
// 101
// 108
// 108
// 111
```

Comment: Why not just `str.utf8.count`?

Comment: For passing the len? Yup that should work too! I was trying to illustrate that you could pass a String type to a function that expects an UnsafePointer<UInt8> without any explicit casting

Answer (score 6):

An answer for people working in Swift 4 now. You can no longer get bytes from a Data object, you have to copy them into an UnsafeMutablePointer

```
let helloWorld = "Hello World!"

let data = helloWorld.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!
var dataMutablePointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: data.count)

//Copies the bytes to the Mutable Pointer
data.copyBytes(to: dataMutablePointer, count: data.count)

//Cast to regular UnsafePointer
let dataPointer = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(dataMutablePointer)

//Your stream
oStream.write(dataPointer, maxLength: data.count)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a string extension for **Swift 5** that you can convert a string to `UnsafePointer<UInt8>` and `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>`

```
extension String {
    func toUnsafePointer() -> UnsafePointer<UInt8>? {
        guard let data = self.data(using: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }

        let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: data.count)
        let stream = OutputStream(toBuffer: buffer, capacity: data.count)
        stream.open()
        let value = data.withUnsafeBytes {
            $0.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
        }
        guard let val = value else {
            return nil
        }
        stream.write(val, maxLength: data.count)
        stream.close()

        return UnsafePointer<UInt8>(buffer)
    }

    func toUnsafeMutablePointer() -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>? {
        return strdup(self)
    }
}
```

To convert `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>` to `String`

```
guard let mutablePointer = "test".toUnsafeMutablePointer() else {
    return
}

let str = String(cString: mutablePointer)
```

Answer (score 4):

By far the easiest way (in Swift 5):

```swift
let s = "hello, world"
let pointer = UnsafePointer(Array(s.utf8CString))
```

Not sure how backwards compatible this is.

Comment: This fails: Cannot convert return expression of type 'UnsafePointer<CChar>' (aka 'UnsafePointer<Int8>') to return type  'UnsafePointer<UInt8>'

Comment: int8_t means char actually and 
UnsafePointer<CChar> and UnsafePointer<Int8> are same both of them signed int8.

But UInt8 is unsigned char so you need to convert signed to unsigned to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I see there are other answers, and an accepted answer, so it seems you've gotten what you need. I came here because I noticed Swift 5's deprecation warnings for `withUnsafeMutableBytes` et al, and started testing @abdullahselek's answer, but I noticed in Swift 5 (haven't yet verified if it worked in previous versions) that `String` is convertible to `UnsafePointer<UInt8>` in-line, so you can use it in place where an `UnsafePointer<UInt8>` is expected. In case it helps to see another example, here's our old and updated function, posted here:

**OLD**

```
let derivationStatus = localDerivedKeyData.withUnsafeMutableBytes { derivedKeyBytes in
  salt.withUnsafeBytes { saltBytes in

    CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(
      CCPBKDFAlgorithm(kCCPBKDF2),
      password,
      passwordData.count,
      saltBytes,
      salt.count,
      algorithm,
      UInt32(rounds),
      derivedKeyBytes,
      derivedKeyData.count
    )
  }
}
```

**NEW**

```
let derivationStatus = localDerivedKeyData.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (outputBytes: UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer) -> Int32 in
  let status = CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(
    CCPBKDFAlgorithm(kCCPBKDF2),
    password, // a String
    passwordData.count, // just the password String converted to Data
    String(data: salt, encoding: .utf8),  // converts salt (Data) to String
    salt.count,
    algorithm,
    UInt32(rounds),
    outputBytes.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self),
    derivedKeyData.count
  )
  return status
}
```

With that said, you could use a similar approach to get your stream as follows:

```
let stream = OutputStream(toBuffer: UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: someString), capacity: someString.data(using: .utf8)!.count)
```

(the ! is used to silence the compiler error, but you should avoid force-unwrapping where possible).

Comment: Hi what is the type of localDerivedKeyData?  and which is the output variable in NEW code here? and

Comment: `localDerivedKeyData` is `Data`. `derivationStatus` is an `Int32` giving you an output status of the operation. `localDerivedKeyData` is written to, byte by byte, by this operation (assume it's a byte array (Data) that has the proper length, just empty to start)

Comment: what is the function throws any error/exception, can you share complete function with use?

Answer (score 1):

I've created a Swift extension that includes this feature among many others for generating pointers from Strings.

It **includes a full test suite** and it supports:

- `myString.stackPointer() -> UnsafePointer<Int8>?`
- `myString.mutableStackPointer() -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?`
- `myString.withUnsignedStackPointer { (ptr: UnsafePointer<UInt8>?) in`
- `myString.withUnsignedMutableStackPointer { (ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?) in`
- `myString.heapPointer() -> UnsafePointer<Int8>?`
- `myString.mutableHeapPointer() -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?`
- `myString.unsignedHeapPointer() -> UnsafePointer<UInt8>?`
- `myString.unsignedMutableHeapPointer() -> UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?`

https://gist.github.com/nathan-fiscaletti/892e074dc14e6707603414cd2d80c287

If you want to test it out you should be able to directly paste it into a Swift Playground.

Answer (score -1):

file.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

Comment: add some description of what was wrong and what this code will correct.